# Search method asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add in a existing controller that sends to the view a table of existing users, and I want to add a search box on the view that searches users by Email or Name, I found this piece of code but don't know if it's right or no.

```
var nameOrEmail = from m in aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers select m;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                nameOrEmail = nameOrEmail.Where(s => s.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }
```

My acctual Controller is like this:

```
public IActionResult Users( string searchString)
    {
        using (var aplicationDbContext = new ApplicationContext())
        { var nameOrEmail = from m in aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers select m;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                nameOrEmail = nameOrEmail.Where(s => s.Email.Contains(searchString) || s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
            var AllUsers = aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers.ToList();

            return View(AllUsers);
        }
    }
```

How can I return the users data and the data from serached ?

Comment: Looks like this would work.

Comment: Wait let me show me controller

Comment: `return View(nameOrEmail.ToList())` to return the filtered users.

Comment: if searchString is empty like this you will bring all users from the db

Comment: `return View(nameOrEmail.ToList());`

Comment: But does this return also the value from User? it doesnt right ?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider can you reply as answer so I accept it ?

Comment: @Izzy can you do that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
return View(nameOrEmail.ToList());
```

You can also get rid of the following lines of code as they will not be used:

```
ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
var AllUsers = aplicationDbContext.ApplicationUsers.ToList();
```

Comment: Glad I could help